# Finding a specific span element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a script to scrape price data from Udemy courses.
I'm struggling with navigating the HTML tree because the  element I'm looking for is located inside multiple nested divs.

here's the structure of the HTML element I'm trying to access:
[image]

what I tried:

```
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
parent_div = doc.find(class_="sidebar-container--purchase-section--17KRp")
print(parent_div.find_all("span"))
```

and even:

```
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
main = doc.find(class_="generic-purchase-section--main-cta-container--3xxeM")
title = main.select_one("div span span span")
```

Here’s the URL: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/

tried searching all the spans in the HTML and the specific span I'm searching for doesn't appear maybe because it's nested inside a div?

would appreciate a little guidance!

Comment: Do you care to share the actual URL?

Comment: Just added sorry about that missed that part

Answer (score 1):

The price is being loaded by JavaScript. So it is not possible to scrape using `beautifulsoup`.

The data is loaded from an [API Endpoint](https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/course-landing-components/1565838/me/?components=price_text) which takes in the course-id of the course.

> Course-id of this course: `1565838`

You can directly get the info from that endpoint like this.

```
import requests

course_id = '1565838'
url= f'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/course-landing-components/{course_id}/me/?components=price_text'
response = requests.get(url)
x = response.json()

print(x['price_text']['data']['pricing_result']['price'])
```

```
{'amount': 455.0, 'currency': 'INR', 'price_string': '₹455', 'currency_symbol': '₹'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your first approach several times and it works more-or-less for me, although it has returned a different number of span elements on different attempts (10 is the usual number but I have seen as few as 1 on one occasion):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/'
response = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
parent_div = doc.find(class_="sidebar-container--purchase-section--17KRp")
spans = parent_div.find_all("span")
print(len(spans))
for span in spans:
    print(span)
```

Prints:

```
10
<span data-checked="checked" data-name="u872-accordion--3" data-type="radio" id="u872-accordion-panel--4" style="display:none"></span>
<span class="purchase-options--option-radio--1zjJ_ udlite-fake-toggle-input udlite-fake-toggle-radio udlite-fake-toggle-radio-small"></span>
<span class="udlite-accordion-panel-title">Subscribe</span>
<span>Try it free for 7 days</span>
<span class="udlite-text-xs purchase-section-container--cta-subscript--349MH">$29.99 per month after trial</span>
<span class="purchase-section-container--line--159eG"></span>
<span data-checked="" data-name="u872-accordion--3" data-type="radio" id="u872-accordion-panel--6" style="display:none"></span>
<span class="purchase-options--option-radio--1zjJ_ udlite-fake-toggle-input udlite-fake-toggle-radio udlite-fake-toggle-radio-small"></span>
<span class="udlite-accordion-panel-title">Buy Course</span>
<span class="money-back">30-Day Money-Back Guarantee</span>
```

As afar as your second approach goes, your *main* div does not have that many nested *span* elements, so it is bound to fail. Try just one *span* element:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/'
response = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
main = doc.find(class_="generic-purchase-section--main-cta-container--3xxeM")
title = main.select_one("div span")
print(title)
```

Prints:

```
<span class="money-back">30-Day Money-Back Guarantee</span>
```